# Can AutoMapper handle nullable child objects in a mapped source model using EF?

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

I've been using AutoMapper (3.1.1 previously and now 3.2.1 in testing this situation) to handle mapping from EF models to disconnected Business Service models. As our usage has expanded I've begun seeing this type of error any time that we're trying to map an EF model that has a nested nullable complex type:

> Unable to create a null constant value of type
>   'BusinessService.Models.TireOptions'. Only entity types, enumeration
>   types or primitive types are supported in this context.

In this simplified example let's say we have a class ConstructionOrder with a member of type TireOptions. In the relational database that EF is modeling, the table ConstructionOrder is defined with a nullable FK to a TireOption table and an appropriate NavigationProperty based on the FK.

This error now occurs everytime we try to map through Project().To() regardless of whether or not there is a value for TireOptions in the returned EF ConstructionOrder model. Prior to upgrading from 3.1.1 to 3.2.1 I was seeing a different error but only when there was no data for the child TireOptions object.

The error that occurred in 3.1.1 was:

> The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value
>   is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must
>   use a nullable type.

This seems like a simple case of handling nested nullable complex types but [this comment from the Entity Framework Triage Team](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/826) makes me think that the expression tree generated by AutoMapper can't be handled by EF. Is this truly the case or is there a work around to dealing with situations like this?